# Rotate array of points according one point

Tags: geometry, point, vector-graphics

I have 4 points and angle (as shown on the picture). How to get new point values for rotated object?

[picture(x/y axis inverted, mistake. Vertical should be Y, horizontal - X)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQxP5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, get coordinates relative to the rotation origin (x0, y0)

```
x' = x1 - x0
y' = y1 - y0
```

Then rotate

```
x'' = x' * Cos(Fi) - y' * Sin(Fi)
y'' = x' * Sin(Fi) + y' * Cos(Fi)
```

And now shift coordinates back

```
x_r = x'' + x0
y_r = y'' + y0
```